# Visual Studio Code Chromebook Linux eats Alt-Tab: can't next-tab programs

Tags: visual-studio-code

On my Pixelbook/Chromebook with VSCode running under the Linux support, Alt-Tab is eaten by VSCode, and not passed to the
host operating system (ChromeOS/Pixelbook my case).

So, you can Alt-Tab (next-window) through all other windows on the Chromebook until you get to VSCode, and there you will stop, because it eats the Alt-Tab key commands.
(or at least that is what seems to be effectively happening)

Surprisingly, I could not find a bound key keybinding in the keyboard shortcuts setup page,
so I may not have a good grip on the exact problem.

I did find a workaround posted below.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to settings.json did seem to do the trick,
although I don't understand why.

```
 // this allows me to use alt-tab on chromebook yeah!
    "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": []
```

This setting is supposed to route keys/commands away from the integrated terminal to VSCode's key handler.
But what I needed/wanted was to stop VSCode's key handler from consuming/stopping Alt-Tab from hitting the host operating system.

This did seem to do the trick, although it is not clear why to me.